# Converting date time value to 10 character date on sql

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, datetime

I'm trying to use the below code to convert the 'date_time' values in my table to 10 characters. Currently, the date_time values are in the format '2020:09:08 10:00:00' but I want to get rid of the time portion of the values so that I'm only left with the date. I'm using DB Browser for SQLite and I thought I would have to use the varchar data type to complete this task but its not working. The output of the code is also shown below.

SELECT CAST(date_time AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM stocks;

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use string functions:

```
substr(date_time, 1, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your datetime values are not valid datetimes for SQLite which recognizes only the format `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'`.
If you used the above format then all you need would be the function `DATE()`:

```
SELECT DATE(date_time) 
FROM stocks;
```

For your current format you must use string functions to extract the first 10 chars and then replace all `:` with `-`:

```
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTR(date_time, 1, 10), ':', '-') 
FROM stocks;
```